# 401 Unauthorized error while using custom scope PAT in preview REST API calls

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

We are noticing 401 Unauthorized error while using custom scope PAT in **preview** REST API calls(Trying to fetch  data related to Deployments/Environments created by Yaml pipelines)

[https://dev.azure.com/{orgnName}/{ProjName}/_apis/distributedtask/environments?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7BorgnName%7D/%7BProjName%7D/_apis/distributedtask/environments?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

[https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}/{ProjName}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{env.Key}/environmentdeploymentrecords?top=2000&api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7BorgName%7D/%7BProjName%7D/_apis/distributedtask/environments/%7Benv.Key%7D/environmentdeploymentrecords?top=2000&api-version=6.0-preview.1)

I tried calling above Restapi calls with below custom scope PATs. But they all resulted in ‘401 unauthorized error’.

Read
Read, Write & Execute
Read, Write, Execute& manage
Read
Read & execute
Read, Write, execute & manage(Release)+Read & execute(build)

Could you please tell me what permissions do I need to grant for PAT to access the environment deployments API.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? If the answers helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. I've tested on my org and only one permission gives access: `Tokens`.

[image]

Comment: We need more   information.
For yaml related pipeline details - Why we need to give token permissions. This might have security implications. Can you please let us know?

Comment: Hi Team, Please let us know  expected estimated time for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can grant Token Administration or Tokens permission for your PAT. The two permissions worked on my side.

[image]

We have reported this issue in Developer Community. Please vote and follow [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1227111/rest-api-for-environments-requires-token-administr.html) for latest updates.

Comment: For yaml related pipeline details - Why we need to give token permissions. This might have security implications. Can you please let us know?

Comment: This is indeed not expected behavior. We have reported this issue to the product group. Please follow [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1227111/rest-api-for-environments-requires-token-administr.html). Hope this issue can be fixed soon.

Comment: Still not fixed...